# Vaadin DateField not showing labels

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

For some strange reason, vaadin's DateField is not showing labels. The month and days of the week aren't showing.

[image]

```
@Component
@UIScope
public class DateOfBirth extends DateField {
    public DateOfBirth(MessageSource messageSource) {
        setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
        setPlaceholder("MM/DD/YYYY");
        setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
}
```

Any thoughts what this could be?

Comment: It could be a problem with your locale. What locale are you using?

Comment: I didn’t think about that, good observation. I’m using Locale(“es”, “ES”). How would I add those resources? Thanks

Comment: @JCCarrillo Could you double check if you get non-null values if you call setLocale for your date field? You can use "es", "ES" locale. It is possible for component to have null locale under certain conditions.

Comment: If you add `super()` to constructor? And/or explicitly `setLocale("es" ,"ES")` in constructor? You're using Spring? In that case how do you instantiate `DateOfBirth`.

Comment: As @pirho says, you should call `super()` so `DateField` can do it's magic.

Comment: big apologies for late response, as suggested, super and setting locale fixed the issue!